# iPhone - how to show a view as pop up

Tags: iphone, popup

How to show a small pop up on click of button on a view that will be displayed in small region of the parent view.

Comment: It's not clear what you want...
Have a look at UIAlertView and UIActionSheet classes - may be they're what you need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply define the frame for your view, and add it as a subview of its parent.

```
newView.frame = CGRectMake(60, 140, 200, 200);
[parentView addSubview:newView];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just putting up a view is pretty straightforward (create a UIView, position it, then addSubview it to the parent). But there are a few UI design questions you may want to ask yourself before you pop something up. Things like:

- Is the pop-up modal? Once it's up can the user do something else or do they have to 'dismiss' the view before continuing.
- How does the user dismiss the view? Do they tap the view itself, some sort of 'close' object, or tap outside of it?
- Where do you position the pop-up view if you're too close to the side of the window (otherwise it gets clipped and the user can't see all of it).
- Should you offset it from the button itself so the tapping finger isn't covering up the item? How many pixels work best? And does the offsetting bring the view too close to the edge, so maybe show it on the other side so it's not clipped?

And they say UI design is easy ;-)